# Communicate between Python processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle, reinforcement-learning

**Context**:

- Controlling a game using [vgamepad](https://pypi.org/project/vgamepad/)
- I have a controller (the brains), and one driver for each instance of the game (4-8 instances)
- I need to send data (instructions and states) between the controller and the drivers
- Speed is key, think 30-60 fps, so we need to run in parallel

**Problem**: When I try to use multiprocessing, on the driver object with a vgamepad object inside, I get the following error `AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'CFUNCTYPE.<locals>.CFunctionType'`. So I can't share the vgamepad objects between processes using multiprocessing. See MRE below:

```
import vgamepad as vg
from multiprocessing import Pool

class Driver:
    def __init__(self):
        self.gamepad = vg.VX360Gamepad()
drivers = [Driver() for _ in range(3)]

with Pool() as pool:
    rst = pool.starmap(Driver, drivers)

>>> AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'CFUNCTYPE.<locals>.CFunctionType'
```

**Solution**:

- Run seperate Python processes, one for the controller, and many for the drivers then configure a messaging API to share data between them. For example, the drivers would send a screenshot of their game, and the controller would send instructions on what to do. For messaging, I was thinking:

  - Pickle and load just the data
  - Fast API

**Question**: What is the best way to share this information between a driver and controller?

- Open to better overall architectures that allow all the data to be kept in memory.

Comment: Pool isn't really suitable for stateful processes but multiprocessing.Process would totally work; and multiprocessing.Pipe or Queue are about as fast as it gets in Python. You could also switch to MPI (with mpi4py) which may have lower latency because MPI typically busy-waits and has optimized communication patterns for 1-to-n and n-to-1

Comment: Actually, multiprocessing.shared_memory used with Mutex and Condition may have lower latency than Pipe or Queue because the latter ones offload the data transfer to a background thread

Comment: @Homer512 I tested using multiprocessing.Process, but when I want to pass the gamepad objects to other processes I get `OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect` due to the same `Can't pickle local object 'CFUNCTYPE.<locals>.CFunctionType'` error

Comment: Why not let the subprocess initialize the gamepad object? If it cannot be pickled, you have to find a way to transfer state changes in pickleable data types

Comment: @Homer512 Yh agreed, sorry I thought your first comment implied mp.Process would allow the objects to be passed through - which makes controlling them a bit easier. To check I understand; I can: 1) create subprocesses which initialise the gamepad objects, 2) communicate with these subprocesses through mp.shared_memory?

Comment: Yes, that would be the fastest, but not necessarily most convenient approach. Also, on Unix systems where subprocesses are created through forking, you can share stuff that cannot be pickled by creating it in the parent process before forking the child process. (since the child inherits the whole memory and file handles of the parent) But that may or may not work out in your case, especially with file handles

Comment: Great, that works - and it's quick. @Homer512 If you want, could you post this as an answer so I can accept it.